# Why still show Y-axis scrollbar on IE11 When use css zoom?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, zooming

Why does IE11 show Y-axis scrollbar when using css zoom ?

I have tested it on other browser and it works ok(not show Y-axis scrollbar), but IE11 still show Y-axis scrollbar. How can I fix the behaviour in IE11?

https://jsfiddle.net/jzjwb9jy/1/

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body style="zoom: 0.25;">
        <img src ="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/3d/df/34/3ddf340436cc77dc9c468505be1ad123.jpg"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fix the behaviour in IE11?

In your css you can use `overflow-y:hidden`, this will disable the Y-axis scrollbar.